# Avoiding GUI freezing on multithreaded operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have a Qt GUI class `preferencesWindow` that, obviously, is responsible for handling the user preferences. I have some fields that manage the connection to a database server. When a field is left, `dbsChanged()` method is called. Below is some code I managed to write:

```
void preferencesWindow::dbsChanged() {
    QFuture<QStringList> loader = run(this, &preferencesWindow::get_databases);
    QStringList databases = loader.result();

    if (databases.length()) {
        this->ui.database->show();
        this->ui.nodb_label->hide();
        this->ui.database->clear();
        this->ui.database->addItems(databases);
        this->ui.okButton->setDisabled(false);
        this->ui.validationStatus->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/icon/tick.png"));
    } else {
        this->ui.database->hide();
        this->ui.nodb_label->show();
        this->ui.okButton->setDisabled(true);
        this->ui.validationStatus->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/icon/error.png"));
    }
}
QStringList preferencesWindow::get_databases() {
    QSqlDatabase test_connection;
    if (QSqlDatabase::contains("PREFEREMCES_LIVE_TEST_CONNECTION"))
        test_connection = QSqlDatabase::database("PREFEREMCES_LIVE_TEST_CONNECTION");
    else test_connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "PREFEREMCES_LIVE_TEST_CONNECTION");
    test_connection.setHostName(this->ui.serverAddress->text());
    test_connection.setUserName(this->ui.username->text());
    test_connection.setPassword(this->ui.password->text());
    test_connection.setDatabaseName(this->ui.database->currentText());
    test_connection.setPort(this->ui.serverPort->value());

    test_connection.open();
    qDebug() << "Error: " << test_connection.lastError();
    QSqlQuery show_databases = test_connection.exec("show databases");
    QStringList databases;
    while (show_databases.next()) {
        databases.append(show_databases.value(0).toString());
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("PREFERENCES_LIVE_TEST_CONNECTION");
    return databases;
}
```

Since `get_databases` can take a long time, I thought that putting in on a separate thread as you can see in these two lines:

```
QFuture<QStringList> loader = run(this, &preferencesWindow::get_databases);
QStringList databases = loader.result();
```

could solve the problem. It runs on a separate thread, but it still freezes the GUI (while working).

**How should I rewrite this entire process?** I though of some solutions, but I am not really sure about their performance, and I don't want to work uselessly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QFutureWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) to monitor that status of the [`QFuture`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfuture.html) object, like written in the documentation:

```
// Instantiate the objects and connect to the finished signal.
MyClass myObject;
QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));

// Start the computation.
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(...);
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

Answer (score 3):

It freezes the GUI because even though the `get_databases` call is in a separate thread, you still wait for the results which causes the freeze.

I don't know how to do it in Qt, but the normal thing would be to open a dialog saying "please wait" or something with a cancel button, and have the worker thread send a signal to the parent (GUI) thread when done.

Comment: It would lead to a worse performance because the process may take from 0.5 seconds to 30 seconds

Comment: @Victor It might lead to worse performance *in some situations* (for example when it would just take 0.5 seconds). If the operation normally takes at least a couple of seconds, how would that lead to worse performance? The time to set everything up (displaying the dialog, start the tread) and tear down (send signal, close dialog) would be negligible in that case.

Comment: @Victor: Joachim is right. Futures are best used in combination with a QFutureWatcher that signals your parent thread when your Future is done. Using a Future like in your current code does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

The QFuture will wait until the thread sets the result when your call `loader.result()`. You have to wait for that value later.

I guess you could store the future object as member of `preferencesWindow` and send yourself a `signal`, when finishing `get_databases`. So you give your application time to process other events during this wait time.